# Preload doesnot work in IE in asp mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I am creating a few audio controls in a table and I dont want to preload audio files. preload="none" is working fine in chrome but not in IE. 
Html code :-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.audioFiles){
 <audio id="@item.id" type="audio/mp3" preload="none" controls src="@Url.Action("LoadMyAudio", new { id= item.id })"/> 
}
```

and in controller I am returning 
    return new FileStreamResult(myAudio, "audio/mp3");

everything works great in chrome/firefox but IE preloads every audio file for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio), the `preload` attribute:

> Represents a *hint* to the UA about whether optimistic downloading of the audio stream itself or its metadata is considered worthwhile. (emphasis mine)

In other words, the browser is under no obligation to do anything at all with this. It *may* choose to handle preloading as you suggest, or it may choose to ignore your preferences entirely and do it any way it pleases.

Further, I cannot find any statistics for the `preload` attribute on an `audio` tag specifically, but as it concerns [generic preload resource hints](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload), no version of IE or Edge currently supports them. In other words, it's entirely possible that IE totally disregards this attribute, and its behavior is simply what it does out of the box for any audio file.

In either case, there's unfortunately nothing you can do about it.